# How can I use the last changed file as an argument in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I'm thinking of using the last changed file as an argument to commands like ls, echo, or cat, is there a simple and efficient way? this question arose when I was faced with analyzing the latest log file or any file that gets written on frequently.

thank you guys.

Comment: In zsh: `echo *(NDom[1])` [or so](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this works? I don't understand those things inside the parentheses, also any other way to do this on non zsh shells?

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`, so I won't elaborate about zsh; I gave you the link to the documentation though. I may be able to kinda solve the problem in bash, but my way would be inelegant and therefore I don't like it. There are similar questions on Stack Exchange, e.g. [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/240418/108618).

Comment: echo $(ls -larth ./ | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f10)

Comment: @Petepf Thank you, but please explain the command in detail.

Comment: @Petepf [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski this is actually now possible with GNU `ls` and its `--zero` flag. not how Petepf suggested, but it is possible. Let me know if you can find a file name that would break my function below, I'm curious!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no really simple way, largely because this needs to work with arbitrary file names. So while something like `ls -tr | tail -n1` will show the last file modified in the current directory, it won't work if the last file's name has a newline. This is easier to explain with an example:

```
$ touch normal_file
$ ls -ltr | tail -n1-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon          0 Mar 11 16:11 normal_file
```

But with a bad file name?

```
$ touch bad$'\n'file
$ ls -ltr | tail -n1
file

$ ls 
'bad'$'\n''file'   normal_file
```

Since the bad file name contains a newline, the `tail` only shows us part of the name. So the straightforward approach `last_file=$(ls -tr | tail -n1)` would fail here.

However, newer versions of `ls` have a `--zero` option:

```
       --zero end each output line with NUL, not newline
```

Which means you can now do exactly that! So, add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
last_file() {
   ls -tr --zero | tail -zn1
}
```

You can now do things like:

```
$ aa=$(last_file)
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
$ echo "$aa"
bad
file
```

So, to pass the last modified file in the current directory as an argument to a command, for example `ls`, you can do:

```
 $ ls "$(last_file)"
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
'bad'$'\n''file'
```

You just need to ignore the warning. Or, we can remove the trailing `\0` this approach requires, by changing the function in your `~/.bashrc` to

```
last_file() {
   ls -tr --zero | tail -zn1 | tr -d '\0'
}
```

Which finally lets us do:

```
$ ls "$(last_file)"
'bad'$'\n''file'
```

This is still not very handy since you need to write `"$(last_file)"` to refer to it. So you could instead make the function set a variable, and then use the function as the value for the special `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable which sets a command that will be run before a new prompt is shown. This means it is run whenever a new shell session starts and after running any command in a terminal. So, add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` instead of the above:

```
last_file() {
  lf=$(ls -tr --zero | tail -zn1 | tr -d '\0')
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="last_file"
```

Now, open a new terminal and you can use the variable `$lf` to show the last file (or directory, if a directory is what was modified last):

```
$ echo "$lf"
bad
file
```

Comment: I'd suggest two changes to your function: `last_file() { ls -dtr --zero "$@" | tail -zn1 | tr '\0' '\n'; }`. Usage now requires a list of files or directories, and no directory is implicitly listed like `ls` does. So `last_file /home/user/*` rather than just `last_file /home/user`. If you don't like that then maybe `last_file() { ( if [ "$#" -le 1 ]; then ls -tr --zero "$@"; else ls -dtr --zero "$@"; fi ) | tail -zn1 | tr '\0' '\n'; }`